# Read csv data directly from url in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, csv, import

I am having some problems reading data from a database in Matlab. The url link I use to download the data gives a semicolon delimited text file and I need Matlab to identify this data and arrange it accordingly in a `struct` format (since the data has different classes) for example.
I have already used `urlread` and could download the data succesfully, the only problem is I am getting all the data as a character string inside one cell and I need to get this data as a table and well organized.

Basically I would like to know if it is possible to load data from a url into Matlab the same way the `read.csv` function in R does, where you just put the url where the file name should go and define how the data is delimited and viola, you get your `data.frame` with all your data perfectly organized as it should.

I suppose there are ways to interpret the character string after using `urlread` and convert it somehow into an organized `struct` variable but there has to be a way to read it directly from the url as R does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that will read the `csv` data from the web (`urlread`), use `textscan` to scan and format the data into cells (strings and scalars allowed), then convert the cells into a structure with `cell2struct`. The structure created keeps the `textscan` formatting.

Note that you have to define the `textscan` format and the `cell2struct` input to suit your data.

```
block = urlread('http://hci.stanford.edu/jheer/workshop/data/florida2000/Florida2000.csv');
C = textscan(block,'%s%s%f%s%f','HeaderLines',1,'EndOfLine','\n');
S = cell2struct(C,{'county','technology','columns','category','ballots'},2)
```

Here is the Florida 2000 Presidential Election Results (`.csv`, 938 data points)

```
county,technology,columns,category,ballots
Alachua,Optical,1,under,217
Alachua,Optical,1,over,105
Alachua,Optical,1,Bush,34124
Alachua,Optical,1,Gore,47365
Alachua,Optical,1,Browne,658
Alachua,Optical,1,Nader,3226
Alachua,Optical,1,Harris,6
...
```

that will produce

```
S = 

    county: {938x1 cell}    %string
technology: {938x1 cell}    %string
   columns: [938x1 double]  %double
  category: {938x1 cell}    %string
   ballots: [938x1 double]  %double
```

---

**Edit**

For double quoted text, you can use `%q` instead of `%s` in calling `textscan` ([FormatSpec options](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec)) just like that

```
C = textscan(fileID,'%q%f');
```

Comment: This solution worked, I had to define for each column the data class and name so its not as straightforward as it is in R. But it does what I want anyway, a good suggestion for mathworks would be to include compatibility with urls in the csvread function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RabidHealer This would involve too much work (supporting all common protocols such as HTTP, FTP, TFTP, etc...), so it usually makes much more sense to limit each command/function/tool with it's own scope of work. If you want to read a remote file, fetch it with the appropriate tool (say `urlread`) and then use another one to parse it.

Comment: I tried this in Octave 3.8.2, but it doesn't work because it ignores 'HeaderLines'. Octave outputs "warning: textscan: 'headerlines' ignored when reading from strings" and actually tries to parse the headers. Is this an Octave quirk not present in Matlab? Anyone know how to get this to work in Octave when not reading from a file?

Comment: What about double quotes in standard csv files? This answer is incomplete.

Comment: @hyprfrcb Please see the edit. `textscan` has a native option for reading quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

Look into a function called `dlmread`. This will allow you to put in a string of data, tell it what the delimiter is, and it should pump out what you need.

[dlmread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)

```
results = dlmread('http://someurl.com/somefile.txt',';')
```

Comment: dlmread work only for numeric data, it creates a matrix. I need to create a structure since the data in the url has different classes

Comment: @RabidHealer The original poster did not really say what the type of data was, so I just assumed it was numeric

Comment: I added a sentence explaining that the data has different classes.

Comment: I tried calling dlmread() with a URL in MATLAB R2015b, but it returned an I/O error. I believe it can only read from the local file system, not from HTTP.

Comment: @Nayuki I cannot say what the problem is without more elaboration on what the error stated, but this answer was written in 2013, so MATLAB may have changed something in the time between when I wrote the answer and when they release R2015b

Comment: `The file could not be opened because: Invalid argument`. That is the error by using this method. I am with R2014b so i dont think this answer is valid even for numeric.